# Proxying site via nginx results in blank page

Tags: nginx, proxy, velo

We have used Wix.com to develop a new version of our website. Since we are using deep linking on iOS, we need to [place a text file in the website root](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). Turns out Wix doesn't support this currently although they are [considering it](https://support.wix.com/en/article/request-coding-your-wix-site).

"No problem," we thought. We can just use an nginx reverse proxy to serve up the `apple-app-site-association` file and proxy the rest of the traffic to Wix. We set this up with the following nginx config:

```
upstream wix {
    keepalive 100;
    server mgertner.wixsite.com:443;
}


server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         getcorkscrew.com;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass https://wix/corkscrew-copy;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         www.getcorkscrew.com;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass https://mgertner.wixsite.com/corkscrew-copy;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

    }
}
```

However, when we go to www.getcorkscrew.com, we just get a blank white page back. Clearly the page is being returned by Wix, and the `head` contains a bunch of scripts and other stuff, but the body just contains:

```
<body>
    <div id="SITE_CONTAINER"></div>
    <div comp="wysiwyg.viewer.components.WixAds" skin="wysiwyg.viewer.skins.wixadsskins.WixAdsWebSkin" id="wixFooter"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"c99d7f1ab0","agent":"","beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","applicationTime":9,"applicationID":"1963269,30200700","transactionName":"ZFAHNkNYXUBQVEUKXF0aNgdDT19WRRhVCkBDVBEBWVxB","queueTime":0}
    </script>
</body>
```

It seems that Wix is somehow detecting the use of a proxy and blocking the normal page content. But when we checked this, we are sending over exactly the same headers as the original request.

Any ideas about how Wix knows we are using a proxy and how we can get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is specific to how Wix renders the site. They embed the URL of the site in their `index.html` and the site won't render if it is loaded from another URL. I don't think they are blocking this on purpose. To me it just looks like a side effect of how the rendering code was implemented.

We fixed this by using an nginx subfilter to change the URL embedded in `index.html` to the one we are proxying from. Now it works fine.

Comment: Hi. Just found your response via Google. I also added a sub_filter `sub_filter "wixdomain.wixsite.com" "$host";` and `sub_filter_once off;` but the site still doesn't render and is white. What sub_filter did you use?

Comment: Did you check what the value of `publicModel` is in the subfiltered `index.html`? It looks to me like at very least you need to include the site name in the filter source (i.e. `wixdomain.wixsite.com/sitename`).

Comment: You mean the `publicModel` json inside the source code? It's already the "correct" one, `var publicModel = {"domain":"wixsite.com","externalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/localhost:8081\/compliance","unicodeExternalBaseUrl":"http:\/\/localhost:8081\/compliance"`

Or are we talking about different things?

Comment: Could you maybe create a gist on GitHub/Pastebin with the contents of your location block where you have the proxy_pass set up? Would like to check it against our config if possible

Comment: Another question: Did you only got this to work on a server with a real domain, or did you also try it out with `localhost`? And do you have the domains connected in wix?

Comment: You can see our rules here: https://gist.github.com/matthewgertner/b784312f72dd2c2b3f2b6b070070a067. It looks to me like you have the `domain` set wrong. We haven't tested with `localhost`, just with a real server. Wix knows nothing about the actual domain we are serving from.

Comment: This is true. They have a js  file where they check for `localhost`. We will deploy our code onto a server and see if it works. Should work. Our config seems similar

Comment: real greate work. It helped to us. But we have little bit another one question. We are moving to our server, and planning moving by parts. Every root "path" of the url is something like "module". This is we are planning to replace a path like `mydomain.com/news` -> `newdomain.com/news`. A main point, we are not going to show new domain, due to after total move we will return old name. So, we wanted to replace a path over nginx-proxy. But, if wix binded with domain - it redirects forcly. How to prevent of redirecting?

Comment: I had to add proxy_ssl_server_name on; as well for it to work properly