# Nginx proxy_pass shows a blank page for wix.com sites

Tags: nginx, proxy, velo

Basically, I have the same problem as

[Proxying site via nginx results in blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064585/proxying-site-via-nginx-results-in-blank-page/44112810?noredirect=1#comment75320332_44112810) and https://serverfault.com/questions/850923/nginx-proxy-wix-site-shows-only-blank-page-in-browser-or-not-found, however there are no "real" solutions provided and I still have the problem of a blank page

This is my location block

```
location /compliance {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter 'wixdomain.wixsite.com' '$host';
    sub_filter_once off;

    proxy_pass http://wixdomain.wixsite.com/compliance;
}
```

However, I still see the blank page, I tried multiple other things, such as

`sub_filter_types text/html text/javascript application/x-javascript` or adding `proxy_pass_request_headers on;` or adding `proxy_set_header Host $host` but none of them worked.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? no css is loaded, every js is loaded without error (200). I'm not sure what I can do anymore to fix this issue. Could this be related that I'm on `localhost:{PORT}` and wix somehow disables it anyway for localhost? Should I try it out with a domain or do you see something else what is already wrong here?

Comment: did you check the nginx error and access log files? If not, could you possible take a closer look at them if you/we can identify any problems?

Comment: There is no content. I think I know the problem. Wix has a javascript files which checks if the hostname is localhost and then doesn't load any css/fonts etc. We will deploy this to a real server and then check out again

Comment: okay, makes sense as wix might (of course) be not "amused" if the webpages are proxied to another location. Depending on the wix webserver configuration, this might also be a Content-Security-Policy (enabled by wix) issue.

Comment: One guy in the ticket I linked managed to display the wix-site, so I think the real problem would be the host.

Answer (score 4):

In my current company we have a purchase flow (wrote in PHP) to buy a product and landing pages built in wix. We use a proxy to all our landing pages are in the same domain that our purchase flow. Our nginx proxy configuration is the following.

```html
server {

  listen 443;

  location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        gzip off;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        add_header Host mi-portal.wix.com;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://mi-portal.wix.com/;
  }

  // Location to use a backend as PHP

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Victor's answer, since it wasn't sufficient for us, as we have included a form on our landingpage.

To serve the wix content at OURDOMAIN.com/info, we used the following configuration:

```nginx
server {

    listen 443;

    location ~ ^/info(\/.*)?$ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass https://XYZ.wixsite.com/info$1;

        sub_filter "XYZ.wixsite.com" "OURDOMAIN.com";
        sub_filter_once off;
    }

    location ~ ^/_api(\/.*)?$ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass https://XYZ.wixsite.com/_api$1;
    }

    # ...
}
```

We had to add a sub_filter and setup a proxy_pass back to the wix API.